# Powershell script to initialize all new drives, format, and give them labels in the OS

Tags: powershell

I have a windows server with 4 additional drives and Im looking for something that initialize all the drives, format them with 64K blocks, label them based on specific names and give them specific drive letters (E, F, G, K).

I've seen this code but it gives the drives letters in order (D, E, F, G) and I'd like to give the drives specific letters.

```
$newdisk = @(get-disk | Where-Object partitionstyle -eq 'raw')
$Labels = @('Backup','Data','System','Logs')

for($i = 0; $i -lt $newdisk.Count ; $i++)
{

$disknum = $newdisk[$i].Number
$dl = get-Disk $disknum | 
Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru | 
New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
Format-Volume -driveletter $dl.Driveletter -FileSystem NTFS - NewFileSystemLabel $Labels[$i] -Confirm:$false


}
```

Comment: You should edit your question and update it with the correct code. Use the _edit_ link underneath your question, please.

Comment: Thanks Olaf... I was on a mobile device trying to edit my post. Not friendly. Its been updated.